# Save client-side changes to server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a very simple site (PHP) that allows user changes (via jQuery) that modify elements' classes, and add/delete rows from a table.

I want to write these changes to the actual PHP file in question on the server every time a user makes a change, so that when the page is refreshed or revisited, the changes remain intact.

What's the simplest / best way to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: You want to make changes to the actual page itself? I mean the file on the server.

Comment: Generally you'd want to define dynamic content in some data structure and store it in a database.  The page would then render the state of whatever's in the database, and changes to that state are saved back to the database.  You don't want to save changes to the *actual* PHP file itself.

Comment: @David You're right in terms of best practice of course, but this is a webpage just for my own use. So I'm not concerned about "unauthorized" changes to the PHP file. I just wanted to do this simple project without involving a MySQL connection if plausible.

Comment: I think, you still should go for changes to db.

Comment: So in the case where I have a table that contains certain rows, you'd suggest keeping the row-by-row information in an SQL table, and likewise for a table whose rows can have different classes added or removed on the client-side, keep that information in an SQL table as well, using ID'd table rows (i.e. `<tr id="1" class="...">...`, etc.)?

Comment: @praguian: You'll find that it's easier to do things the right way, honestly.  If you're intent on modifying the file itself, you won't find a lot of help or examples because it's something that just isn't done, for several reasons.  A database-driven approach is considerably simpler and has fewer problems.

Comment: @David Alright, alright, I'll do it the right way (though it won't be *easier* since I have to connect to a MySQL DB where I didn't have to previously ;) ).

Comment: @praguian: No, it will be easier.  It will also be more reliable.  If you want, you can implement it both ways and see for yourself.

Comment: @praguian Yes, that's the idea. Also, if you do not see the classes' names changing in the future, prefer your idea of using ID'd table rows, as the approach suggested in my answer would be of more-than-necessary complexity for the requirement.

Comment: @David: "Easier" and "more reliable" are two different things. ;)

Comment: @praguian if the page is only yours to modify and very simple. Why not edit it directly?

Comment: @Bart: Because the page's function will be to track changes I'm monitoring externally very rapidly. I do not plan to have to reload or revisit the page during this time, but I want to have my changes covered in case of an unforeseen interruption to my client-side operations. I've got it all working with the use of MySQL now, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For addition/deletion of rows**, fire ajax call and update records associated with the user. This is in addition to client-side (jQuery/JavaScript) changes to page. Whenever they revisit/refresh the page, data will be fetched from db, and as such will always be latest.

When you say that **users modify elements' classes**, I assume you mean their page's looks and styling (like some sites have on-page options to change background color, font-sizes). If that is the case, I suggest you:

1. Create a list of all possible states and store them in a new table in db, say `display_options`. You could store details like `option_type` (e.g. background color, font-size etc) and `option_back_value` (e.g. #FFF, #000 etc).
2. Create a new table say `user_display_options` where you store things like `user_id`, `option_type` and their chosen `option_id`.
3. *While loading page*, do a `join` on these tables using `user_id`. Then while creating your page, conditionally add classes etc to the page.
4. *When user edits page*, fire ajax call sending required data like `user_id`, `option_type`, `option_id`. As mentioned for other task, these changes to db will be in addition to client-side changes.

Also read @David 's comment to your question - it clears an important concept.